# spring-boot actuator healthcheck events

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Is it possible to listen an event emitted when there is a change in one of the health check indicators? So that I can have an `ApplicationListener` on this type of events?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar need and I investigated a little bit.

The health information is retrieved on a pull-based manner when the actuator endpoint gets called.
The health indicators don't get updated when the underlying status changes, so a listener would be more or less useless.

Nevertheless, one could still implement a custom health indicator that listen to events and propagates them to other listeners.